# Drag&Drop between two/more WPF listboxes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, drag-and-drop, listboxitems

I am trying to do the following: 
I have two list-boxes and I want to be able to drag an item from the first one and drop it into the second one.

This works but I have problems when I want to drag an item from the second and drop it in the first one.

If I set "AllowDrop=true" for the first one and use the same code in the PreviewMouseButtonDown and drop, It happens that I can drop in item onto itself.

When I click an item DoDragDrop is called and then Drop. I tried to avoid this by checking if the drag source and the target are the same but after I've done this I've seen that I need to double-click an item in the list-box if I want to select an item. This is annoying and unwanted because sometimes I don't want to move an item to another list-box.

I wish I can select an item by click (see it highlighted) and If I hold down my left button and move the mouse to be able to drop it into the second list-box. Basically, any list-box in my small app should allow dropping and should also be a drag source.

Is it possible that a list-box be a drag-source and a drop target at the same time and avoid dropping its items into itself, this while the user can still select an item with a single click for other actions?

My source was [this project](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/drag-and-drop-item-in-listbox-in-wpf/) but I've added some custom strings in my first list-box, not all the time zones.

Comment: you can bind AllowDrop to your property and check where item originated from

Comment: Hi @Muds! I've tried this also. I've created a property and I've done the binding, but I have the problems with clicking one item in the list-box to select it. I have to click twice if I want that item to be highlighted.

Comment: thats a separate issue, check SO there are lot of threads talking about why it can take two clicks to select an item, also try pasting your code with your question so it helps people find out if did a silly glitch somewhere